# Travel to Romania with German Work visa

Tags: germany, working-visas

I have work visa for Deutschland (Germany) which is valid till August and I plan to travel Romania for 3 days in April. Do I need Romania visa too? I don't have residence permit as of now.

Comment: How do you have a visa yet not a residence permit? I guess it would be better to get one as soon as possible or at least get the temporary document that proves you live in Germany. Visa works in many occasions but without the residence permit a lot of things can get a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

[**ON MINISTRY OF FOREIGN AFFAIRS OF ROMANIA'S WEBSITE;**](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040)

**Categories of third-state nationals also exempt from the requirement to be in possession of a Romanian short-stay visa are:**

Holders of biometric passports, nationals of the following states:

*the Republic of Moldova; the Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia;
the Republic of Serbia, except for the passports issued by the Serbian Coordination Division (in Serbian: Koordinaciona uprava); the Republic of Montenegro (the non-biometric passports issued by this state are no longer valid).*

- The holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States.

**Attention!** The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by the Schengen Member States.

- The holders of permanent residence permits issued by the UK or Ireland. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per such residence permits.
- The holders of visas or residence permits issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia.

**Attention!** The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per such visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per such visas/residence permits.

so the answer to your question is **NO**, you don't need a Romanian visa to enter Romania but instead you can enter Romania with the German work visa.